# How to refresh main screen with new language?

Tags: android

I have an Android app with a main screen and various buttons and controls which can take the user to other activities.   One of those activities can allow the user to switch to another locale.     (eventually there will be lots of other locales).  When the user sets a locale it's stored in non-volatile storage so it's remembered next time the app starts up.

I have resource folders each with their own a **strings.xml** file for every language, and so the main screen's buttons and labels are populated from the current language's resource file is.  I set it just before I do a *setContentView()* . . .

```
readPrefs();  // populate class variables from n.v. storage
// set the current locale...
Resources res = this.getResources();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = new Locale(MyApp.locale);   //new Locale(locale);
res.updateConfiguration(conf, res.getDisplayMetrics());
// inflate the main view (it will use the locale set above) ...
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

When the user selects a new locale his selection is read from a dropdown and stored in a variable ("MyApp.locale" in this example code) as well as in non-volatile storage.  In this example I just have Romanian and English) . . .

```
localeSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spCountries);
String locale = localeSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
if (locale.equals("Romanian"))  {
    MyApp.locale = "RO";
}
else  {
    MyApp.locale = "EN";
}
    savePrefs();    //Commit params to storage
```

... this works fine except that because the main screen is only drawn once when that activity is first started and I do the *setContentView()*, there is nothing to force it to be **re**-drawn using the new language's strings.xml.

Is there anyway to force it to refresh or re-inflate the main activity's screen using the new locale?

Comment: why not restart the activity / app?

Comment: Why are you using this instead of the phone's global locale?  If there isn't a very good reason to not just use the device locale, you shouldn't fight the system.  Users who actually want to change languages know how to do it already.

Comment: Why don't you use, for example, `Activity`'s `recreate()` method as per [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942535/using-locale-to-force-android-to-use-a-specific-strings-xml-file-for-a-non-suppo/40986218#40986218)?

Comment: @ Gabe Sechan _Why are you using this instead of the phone's global locale?_   Because the languages I want to use are not natively supported on this device.