# Set system locale in device

Tags: android, configuration, settings, locale

anyone know it's possible to set system language for device programmatically?
I know about problem where we cant use

```
`android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION`
```

(google changed it in android 5.0+) 
I was tested it with reflect methods. And its work only when we grant permission with adb.(its not correct way )

```
adb grant mypackage android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION
```

My app have a admin rights, i hope maybe there another way when my app is admin app and i can change device locale programmaticaly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942535/using-locale-to-force-android-to-use-a-specific-strings-xml-file-for-a-non-suppo/40986303#40986303

Answer (score 0):

This code mimics the effect of doing it manually through the settings app:

```
String locale = "en-US";
Locale loc = null;

String[] langCountry = locale.split("-");
if (langCountry.length == 2) {
    loc = new Locale(langCountry[0], langCountry[1]);
} else {
    loc = new Locale(locale);
}
LocalePicker.updateLocale(loc);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: From https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/LocalePicker.java : "Each listener needs to call updateLocale(Locale) to actually change the locale."

Answer (score -1):

This method does the bulk of the work. Edit Accordingly

```
   private static boolean updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return true;
    }
```

it selects a new locale from the language string that You passed in, and then updates the app’s resource files.

Comment: this method work only for APP , i need for system language.