# Preventing from using en_US as the default locale

Tags: android, localization, locale

I am having problem in changing locale at run time in android app . I have created **"values-en"** and **"values-mm"** folders and translated the strings into respective locale. Whenever I am trying to change the locale, locale has changed but the string resources are not using **"values-mm"**. It keep using **"en"** values even if I refresh the layouts. When I changed the name of **"values-mm"** to **"values-en"** , then **"values-mm"** resources are loaded. 
So I have concluded that no matter what , only **"values-en"** is loaded.
I can't find the reason why . But the locale did changed.
Any Idea what went wrong? 
How can I set the locale that user had chosen as the fall back locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While updating your Local with in configurations like this you will update then the language will be changed.

```
    public static void changeLocale(Context context, String locale) {
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = new Locale(locale);
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

You can find the reference link : [Using Locale to force Android to use a specific strings.xml file for a non-supported language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942535/using-locale-to-force-android-to-use-a-specific-strings-xml-file-for-a-non-suppo?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: You have saved my 40+ hours of debugging.. You saved the day!! Thank you !!