# Android 9. Doesn't set localization in app

Tags: android, localization

This is my code for switching app language:

```
  public static void changeLanguageApp(Context context, Locale locale) {
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        Configuration config = res.getConfiguration();
        Locale currLocale = getLocale(config);
        Configuration conf;
        if (currLocale != locale) {
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            conf = new Configuration(config);
            conf.setLocale(locale);
            res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }
```

when app is running switching works good. But if I close app and then run it, there are language of device, not of app. When I run my app I use this code:

```
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  loadResources(this);
}

    public static Context loadResources(Context context) {
     return changeLocale(context, this, getResources().getConfiguration().locale);
    }

public static Context changeLocale(Context context, Locale locale) {
    Locale currentLocation = new Locale(locale.getLanguage());
    Locale.setDefault(currentLocation);
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        config.setLocale(currentLocation);
        context = context.createConfigurationContext(config);
        res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    } else {
        config.locale = locale;
        res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    return context;
}
```

In debug I see, that app language detected right, but I dont understend, why doesn't it set for app.
Such situation is on Android 9 and some devices Android 11.

Comment: Would [Using Locale to force Android to use a specific strings.xml file for a non-supported language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40942535/3290339) help?

Comment: @Onik
I have tried all these suggestion, but still get this behaviour.